# "one " used as pro-form

Tags: articles, pronouns

The following is from a grammar book:

> 1) a. She was still working.  b. Was she still working?
>
> The contrast in (1) is one of clause type, with （a）declarative and （b） interrogative.

Questions:

1. Does "one" stand for "contrast" and it could be substituted with "that"？
2. Isn't "type"a count noun, which requires an article？

Comment: "One" is indefinite and in this context it means "a contrast". If you use "that", it is definite and means "the contrast". You can use "that", but the meaning will be slightly different. I'm not sure why we don't need an article before "clause type".

Comment: @user178049 Thanks for your help.